# How to avoid proximity sensor to interrupt my own TTS when TalkBack is active

Tags: android, text-to-speech, talkback, proximitysensor

I'm developing an app that uses TTS to speak.

However, it is going to be used on phones that probably have accessibility and TalkBack enabled, as it is meant to be used by the visually impaired.

The problem (among others I'm struggling with) is that, if TalkBack's option to interrupt speech with the proximity sensor is enabled, the proximity sensor will not only interrupt speech initiated by TalkBack, it will also interrupt TTS speech initiated by my own app.

How do I avoid that? (I'd love to disable TalkBack altogether from the app, but shamefully that is not even possible)

Comment: I see you already had [reported](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76162) this issue and got an answer. You may want to post that as an answer to help people searching for solution.

Comment: That's a bug report and the answer I got there is that it is fixed in more recent versions of Android (though i haven't verified). The question here is if there is a workaround.